# JQUERY Uncaught TypeError: Index Of

Tags: jquery, function

What I want to do is when I click a button some rows of my table should be hidden.
To do that I use JQuery.

I tried with the following script and it working fine (as long as I keep commented line as it is).

```
<button href="#" id="axthis" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"> 
        HIDE/SHOW  </button>
<table id = "testform" class ="table table-bordered">

    <thead>

        <tr class ="success">
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'> BLABLA1 </th>
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'>  BLABLA2 </th>
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'>  BLABLA3 </th>
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'>  BLABLA4 </th>
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'>  MODEL ROW </th>
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'>  BLABLA5 </th>
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'> Background </th>
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'>  BLABLA6 </th>
            <th data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="click for filtering" class="text-center" style='font-size:90%'> BLABLA7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
<?php

        foreach($allcfs as $res){
            print("<tr>");
               $loli = $res["OptNo"];
               print("<td style='font-size:90%'> <a href=\"" . $loli. "\" target=\"_blank\">".  $res["OptNo"] . " </a> </td>");
               print("<td style='font-size:90%'>{$res["Title"]}</td>");
               print("<td style='font-size:90%'>{$res["cpNo"]}</td>");
               print("<td style='font-size:90%'>{$res["APNo"]}</td>");
               print("<td class ='amodel' style='font-size:90%'>{$res["AModel"]}</td>");
               if($res["RequestedBy"] == 1){
                print("<td style='font-size:90%'> PA </td>");
               }
               else {
                print("<td style='font-size:90%'> AEE </td>");
               }
               print("<td style='font-size:90%'>{$res["Background"]}</td>");
               print("<td style='font-size:90%'>{$res["ND"]}</td>");
               print("<td style='font-size:90%'>{$res["NSD"]}</td>");
           print("</tr>");
        }
?>   
     </tbody>
</table>






<script>
            //$("#axthis").click(function(){        
                    var allrows = $('tbody tr');
                    allrows.each(function() {

                        var amodele = $(this).find(".amodel").html(); 

                        if (amodele.indexOf("4G") >= 0){
                            console.log('blabla');
                        }
                        else{
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    });
            //});
</script>
```

However what I want to do is that the user can choose either to hide or not by clicking a button.

So when I add the query condition (I remove commented line on above script part) to get it working on click, that's actually no longer working and I got prompted this 
error message:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf'** of undefined
So it is weird it is looks like this function is not longer recognized.

Anyone to help?

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well?

Comment: `atmodele` is `null` or `undefined`. you better provide html also

Comment: So that means `atmodele` is undefined.

Comment: ok here you are I added html code.

Comment: it's not relevant, paste the table structure

Comment: Is your script at the top or bottom of the page? The only difference between running your script as above vs without the commented out lines is when it is executed. `.html()` returns null if no elements were found... which would cause your error when you call `.indexOf`

Comment: the script is at the bottom

Comment: if you debug you will see amodele is null.
Or use alert(amodele);

Which probably means its not inside the Table row or your selector is wrong.

Also Not seeing any references to bmodel

Comment: still not enough, where's the element with class `bmodel` ? Show us an entire `tr`

Comment: If you can include the final, rendered HTML of the table, it would be most helpful.

Comment: I am sorry guys for not enough information but many confidential information, so I need to parse it first to make sure.

Comment: I'm guessing it's going to be something weird like, you have Javascript that creates another table asynchronously that lacks the bmodel class,  I'd recommend restricting `$('tbody tr')` to guarantee you only get the tbody you care about.

Comment: To all I appreciate your support even though I realize low information but this is due to confidential info.
Anyway my point is code is doing what I expect without commented line but I need to remove them to let the choice to the user.

Comment: @Oeiloff you can put the dummy data based on your table structure.

Comment: I added table html, hope it can help

Comment: TYPO - should axthis be athis?

Comment: That's not the HTML, that's PHP.

Comment: No axthis sorry. As I said working when keeping commented lines in script.

Comment: @daniel, that's php indeed, but server will spit out html at the end, please consider what inside print function as the html rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to some of your comments, I believe i could figure out why it was not working when leaving commented lines.

basically for a reason I don't know when I remove the commented lines, amodele object can be undefined, so I have first to test if undefined otherwise indexOf function failed.

Herebelow script working (added line with stars).

```
<script>
            $("#axthis").click(function(){        
                    var allrows = $('tbody tr');
                    allrows.each(function() {

                        var amodele = $(this).find(".amodel").html(); 
           **if(typeof amodele != "undefined"){**
                        if (amodele.indexOf("4G") >= 0){
                            console.log('blabla');
                        }
                        else{
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
            **}**
                    });
            });
</script>
```